# Fixed-point-free action and cohomology of a finite group

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

I learned that "If $G$ is a finite group acting freely and continuously on $S^n$, the sphere then $G$ has periodic cohomology".

My question is: Are there any other similar theorems relating the free action of a finite group and its cohomology?

maybe this question is too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out Alex Adem's paper:

*Adem, Alejandro*, [**Cohomological restrictions on finite group actions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(88)90025-4), J. Pure Appl. Algebra 54, No.2-3, 117-139 (1988). [ZBL0686.57023](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0686.57023).
If you look at the papers which cite this one on *Google Scholar* some wisdom may likewise ensue.